# How to write this MySql query on Laravel Controller?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

This is my query on MySql and I want to write it on Laravel. How to write this MySql query on Laravel Controller? Beacuse i try to write it on laravel and the result is different from MySql

```
SET @row_num=0;
SELECT @row_num:=@row_num+1, 
       model.name, date, 
       sum(a), sum(b), 
       SUM(SUM(b)) OVER(PARTITION BY model.name ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),
       IF(@row_num>2, SUM(SUM(b)/3) OVER(PARTITION BY model.name ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) , NULL)
FROM table INNER JOIN model ON table.id_model = model.id
WHERE id_model = 1
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Step 0: Indent that query so it's easier to work with

---

---

I used https://codebeautify.org/sqlformatter for this. The result was the following:

```sql
SET 
    @row_num = 0;
SELECT 
    @row_num := @row_num + 1, 
    model.name, 
    date, 
    sum(a), 
    sum(b), 
    SUM(
        SUM(b)
    ) OVER(
        PARTITION BY model.name 
        ORDER BY 
            date ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING 
            AND CURRENT ROW
    ), 
    IF(
        @row_num > 2, 
        SUM(
            SUM(b)/ 3
        ) OVER(
            PARTITION BY model.name 
            ORDER BY 
                date ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING 
                AND CURRENT ROW
        ), 
        NULL
    ) 
FROM 
    table 
    INNER JOIN model ON table.id_model = model.id 
WHERE 
    id_model = 1 
GROUP BY 
    date
```

### Step 1: Identify different statements.

---

---

Your query (or queries) have 2 statements. a `SET` statement and a `SELECT` statement.

### Step 2: Translate the statements to Query Builder if possible.

---

---

Start with the shortest/easier one first

#### Step 2.1: Translate the `SET` Statement.

---

To run a statement where we don't care about the results (just that it runs), `DB::statement()` can be used. This will mostly be copying the SQL.

```php
DB::statement('SET @row_num = 0');
```

#### Step 2.2: Translate the `SELECT` statement.

---

For complex SQL queries, the easiest way to translate them is to run them with `tinker` and check if they are the same when using `toSql()`.

1. Create a temporary .php file: `touch myquery.php`.
2. Write your query work-in-progress in your temp php file, finish with `->toSql();` and dump the results.

[image: Step 2.2.2: Query WIP]

3. Run it through `tinker`: `php artisan tinker myquery.php`

[image: Step 2.2.3: Query WIP Output]

4. Keep working on the query in your temp php file
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 until the query is the one you want.

---

Again, we can start with the easy parts.

| SQL | Query Builder |
| --- | --- |
| `INNER JOIN model ON table.id_model = model.id` | [`join('model', 'table.id_model', 'model.id')`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#inner-join-clause) |
| `WHERE id_model = 1` | [`where('id_model', 1)`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses) |
| `GROUP BY date` | [`groupBy('date')`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#groupby-having) |

Now the query should look like this:

```php
$query = DB::table('table')
    ->join('model', 'table.id_model', 'model.id')
    ->where('id_model', 1)
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->toSql();
```

As for the columns selected; many of them are aggregate functions so the use of [`selectRaw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#selectraw) is needed. As the name implies, you pretty much pass raw SQL to it. You can put it all in a single `selectRaw()` but I prefer to use one per column for readability.

As a result, the final query looks like this:

```php
$query = DB::table('table')
    ->selectRaw('@row_num := @row_num + 1')
    ->selectRaw('model.name')
    ->selectRaw('date')
    ->selectRaw('sum(a)')
    ->selectRaw('sum(b)')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(SUM(b)) OVER (PARTITION BY model.name ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)')
    ->selectRaw('IF(row_num > 2, SUM(SUM(b)/3) OVER (PARTITION BY model.name ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), NULL)')
    ->join('model', 'table.id_model', 'model.id')
    ->where('id_model', 1)
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->toSql();
```

And there, it should be done.

[image: Finished Query]
[image: Generated SQL for finished Query]

### Step 3: Cleanup

---

---

#### Step 3.1: Copy the queries to your Controller or wherever you need to use them.

---

```php
DB::statement('SET @row_num = 0');
$results = DB::table('table')
    ->selectRaw('@row_num := @row_num + 1')
    ->selectRaw('model.name')
    ->selectRaw('date')
    ->selectRaw('sum(a)')
    ->selectRaw('sum(b)')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(SUM(b)) OVER (PARTITION BY model.name ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)')
    ->selectRaw('IF(row_num > 2, SUM(SUM(b)/3) OVER (PARTITION BY model.name ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), NULL)')
    ->join('model', 'table.id_model', 'model.id')
    ->where('id_model', 1)
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->get();
```

#### Step 3.2: Delete temp php file.

---

Answer (score 0):

You can try `DB::statement()` or `DB::unprepared()`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.